# What can I do to make an image appear before my app launch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I´m doing an app for iPhone in objective-c, and before my app launches I want a splash screen to appear.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a "splash screen"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980610/implementing-a-splash-screen-in-ios

Comment: Are you referring to iOS or OSX development?

Comment: thanks veredesmarald, i wanted something  like  this, and if I want it last more  time  how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As veredesmaralad answered, you can use an application launch image, but it's not really intended for use as a splash screen. It's intended to give the user immediate feedback that the app is launching, yet give the app some time to initialize. This image is displayed by the OS until your app puts its window on screen. The display time will vary from device to device.

If I were trying to do something more involved such as displaying the splash screen for a longer time, or animating the splash screen, I would display a view for the splash screen, then move on to the main app. I might just have my main `UIViewController` show the view, and then have an `NSTimer` tell the controller when to replace the view with the next view (e.g. the main user interface). For a more involved animated splash screen I might use a dedicated `UIViewController` to run that animation. Then when the animation completes I'd have the splash screen's controller load the next controller.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [Application Launch Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rename any image you want to "Default.png" and just add it in your project. That's all. Application will display that image while your app is loading.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is called a "splash screen" and you may want to read up about it from [somewhere like Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen).

The answer to this question will depend heavily on what programming language you're using. If you could provide better explanation, a better answer can be given.

Comment: The programming language is Objective-C.

Comment: @BoltClock I see that now, I think the tag wasn't there beforehand. Thanks, though.