# How to create a Welcome View

Tags: ios, animation, viewcontroller

I'm making an app and i want to create a Welcome View Controller with an image showing the app logo and my company logo, and after a few seconds, the app initializes.

This is very commom at mobile games. I don't know even how to start.

I searched for related questions but found nothing.

Comment: Apple specifically recommends to *not* have splash screens of this sort in an iOS app. Unfortunately, they are common with mobile games (which evolved from console games, where there are often contractual and legal requirements to fulfill), but that doesn't mean they're a good pattern to follow, especially for your app.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is called Splash Screen: [Implementing a splash screen in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980610/implementing-a-splash-screen-in-ios)