# Splash screen for IOS in xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement Splash Screen for IOS in My app I studied many posts but was not able to get any useful result.I also went through the following link [Implementing a splash screen in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980610/implementing-a-splash-screen-in-ios) but was not able to implement a splash screen to my already built app.

Comment: what have you done so far, what is failing, what did you expect exactly, why did you fail to add it to your application?

Comment: studied many posts ? for Splash screen, do you mean Launch Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented splash screen using following method and it worked for me

Add following code to your appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *splashView;
```

In Appdelegate.m insert the following code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[_window addSubview:_viewController.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash screen.png"];
[_window addSubview:_splashView];
 [_window bringSubviewToFront:_splashView];
```

add the following line to application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

and implement the following function somewhere in appdelegate.m

```
-(void)removeSplash;
{
    [_splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [_splashView release];
}
```

Comment: Really? Why don't you use Launch Image ?

Comment: I __would not__ recommend to add _any_ subviews to a `UIWindow` instance. that is highly improper pattern with an `UIWindow`.

Comment: @holex can u plz explain it how to do so

Comment: @Sarao, yes, the 'splash' screen should be part of the view hierarchy of a simple `UINavigationController` as a root view controller for instance.

Comment: Hi Holex Actually i am quite new to iphone programming and started so only 2 weeks back. I implemented splash screen in this way. If you can provide a better way it will be highly appreciated. what is the effect of implementing spalsh screen in the way i have done.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your **Project setting** and in  **General tab**  there is section named **App Icon and Launch Images**

You can user `xcassests`, by *Launch Images Source* Use it click on **Use Asset Catalog** button, and you can add your splash screens over there for different sizes.